# Specifying Python Headers and Library for SWIG

Tags: c++, linux, python-3.x, python-2.7, swig

I have two versions of python installed 2.7 and 3.3.

And when I tried to generate the wrapper with SWIG 1.3.4, I did something like this:

```
swig -c++ -python -I/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/include/python3.3m mylib.swig
```

And then, I tried to compile it with g++ 4.6

```
g++ -L/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib64 -Wl,-Bstatic -lz -lboost_date_time-mt -Wl,-Bdynamic -lpython3.3m -lbz2 -lpthread -lrt -ldl -O2 -fPIC -shared mylib_wrap.cxx -I.. -I/opt/rh/python33/root/usr/include/python3.3m -I/server/zodiac/include -std=gnu++0x -o _mylib.so
```

But then, I got error like this:

```
mylib_wrap.cxx: In function ‘swig_module_info* SWIG_Python_GetModule()’:
mylib_wrap.cxx:2453:51: error: ‘PyCObject_Import’ was not declared in this scope
mylib_wrap.cxx: In function ‘void SWIG_Python_SetModule(swig_module_info*)’:
mylib_wrap.cxx:2522:92: error: ‘PyCObject_FromVoidPtr’ was not declared in this scope
mylib_wrap.cxx: In function ‘swig_type_info* SWIG_Python_TypeQuery(const char*)’:
mylib_wrap.cxx:2545:60: error: ‘PyCObject_AsVoidPtr’ was not declared in this scope
mylib_wrap.cxx:2550:51: error: ‘PyCObject_FromVoidPtr’ was not declared in this scope
```

Then, I looked into Python 2.7's and 3.3's headers.  I noticed that those expressions are defined in Python 2.7's headers but not 3.3.

So it seems to me even though I specified the include path to Python 3.3 when I asked SWIG to generate the wrapper, it still tried to use 2.7.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use a more recent version of SWIG and this goes away. Depending on exactly which version of SWIG 1.3 you have installed there may be a `-py3` option for it.

Comment: @Flexo it is 1.3.4.  I did try something like swig -c++ -python -py3 mylib.swig without the -I, and it gave me the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SWIG 1.3.4 is ancient. It's not compatible with Python 3.3. You need to use a newer version of SWIG if you want to produce code that is compatible.